# Wrapping a string into a set number of lines

Tags: r, string, split, strsplit

I have a set of strings such as

```
x <- c("xxx", "xxx xxx", "xxx xxxx xxx", "xxx xxxx xxx xxxxxx")
```

and I want to wrap each so that they fall over two lines, with the breaks where there are spaces, roughly in the middle of the strings, i.e. an output such as

```
"xxx" "xxx\nxxx" "xxx\nxxxx xxx" "xxx xxxx\nxxx xxxxxx"
```

I thought `strwrap` would work, but I cannot figure out how set a width that does will avoid outputs straying on to a third line

Comment: What are the exact rules for where the line breaks should be inserted.  You haven't actually given us very clear rules here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen spaces... as strwrap would work

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question.  _Which_ spaces, or where should the breaks occur?

Comment: Roughly in the middle of the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any built in function that does this, but you can find the "middle-most" space and replace it with a new line with a function like this:

```
two_line_wrap <- function(x) {
  mapply(function(spaces, length, string) {
    if(all(spaces==-1)) return(string);
    breakp <- spaces[which.min(abs(spaces-length/2))]
    substr(string, breakp, breakp) <- "\n"
    string
  }, gregexpr(" ", x), nchar(x), x)
}

two_line_wrap(x)
# [1] "xxx"                  "xxx\nxxx"            
# [3] "xxx\nxxxx xxx"        "xxx xxxx\nxxx xxxxxx"
```